# How to display image in magento admin top menu like sweet tooth rewards?

Tags: magento

How to display image in magento admin top menu?. Exactly like sweet tooth rewards extension

Comment: @mikedan you mean admin menu toplink?

Comment: Yes Venkat. I have tried in config.xml using cdata. But it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to the link you want to put up an image.

```
<reference name="top.links">
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>My account</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
            <title>My account</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
            <liParams/>
            <aParams>class="classname"</aParams>
            <beforeText/>
            <afterText/>
     </action>       
 </reference>
```

Add the four lines which are in between `position tag` and `action tag` ie,

```
<liParams/>
<aParams>class="classname"</aParams>
<beforeText/>
<afterText/>
```

Hope this is useful.